# Apache2 custom 404 Page won't load (.htaccess)

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, apache2

i want to create a custom errorpage for my small webserver which runs on apache2 on raspbian. But sadly the created page isn't loaded by a browser in case of an URL which can't be resolved ... the browser just prints the path to the created errorpage on the upper left-hand corner.

html of the custom page so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><p>Nooooot found ...</p></body></html>
```

html of the loaded page:

```
<html><head></head><body>sites/errorsites/404.html</bod></html>
```

My .htaccess-file, which is placed in /var/www/

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 sites/errorsites/404.html
```

Location of my errorsites-dir with custom errorsites: /var/www/sites/

(Of course I set "AllowOverride" in the default-file in /etc/apache2/sites-available to "all".)

Thanks for the help

Lukas

**Edit:**
default-file of apache:

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ErrorDocument docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ErrorDocument):

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the
>   DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve.
>   Alternatively, a message can be provided to be displayed by the
>   browser.

`sites/errorsites/404.html` does not begin w/ a slash and so is treated as a message to be displayed. Changing it to `/sites/errorsites/404.html` should fix, if `sites` is relative to your DocumentRoot…